# Upload Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando fazer o upload de imagens via AJAX e PHP, porém sem sucesso. Já revisei, atualizei, enfim, os códigos batem com todos os outros códigos que eu pesquisei, eu realmente não estou entendendo.

HTML:

```
<form class="photo_change" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input class="arquivo" name="img" type="file" />
                <input type="submit" class="img_envia" name="envia_img" value="SELECIONAR IMAGEM" />
                <img style="display: none; width:22px; height: 22px; margin-left:10px;" src="/img/loader.gif" /> </form>
```

Jquery:

```js
$('.img_envia').click(function(){
                    $('.arquivo').trigger('click');
                    return false;
});
 
                $('.arquivo').change(function() {
                  var fileName = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
                  var formData = new FormData($('.photo_change'));
                  $('#modal_photo_content form img').show();
 
                      $.ajax({
                        url:'http://localhost/photo_change.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            $('.img_envia').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $('.img_envia').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
                            alert("ERRO: Tente novamente mais tarde.");
                        }
                      });
 
                });
```

E no PHP eu estou dando um var_dump na variável $_FILES e no $_POST para ver se estou recebendo algo, mas o retorno é sempre o da foto:
[image: console log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`FormData` suporta apenas o `<form>` no construtor](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Se o `.photo_change` é o form, penso que podes fazer, nota que tem o `[0]` visto que o `FormData` espera o elemento HTML e nao o objecto jQuery.

```
var formData = new FormData($('.photo_change')[0]);
```

Ou, podes usar o append.

```
var theFile = $(this)[0].files[0];
var fileName = theFile.name;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append(fileName, theFile);
```

Comment: Obrigado. Muito objetivo. :)
Prefiro a primeira maneira, já que a validação no PHP fica mais fácil.

Comment: var formData = new FormData($('.photo_change').get(0));
Essa opção também faz a mesma coisa.